# openpyxl - "unexpected keyword argument 'WindowHeight' " while opening a XLSX File

Tags: excel, keyword, xlsx, openpyxl

I'm trying to simply open a file with `openpyxl` but it gives me an error!

[image]

I really need to solve this! Thanks for any help

Comment: You should add the code of the file you trying to launch

Comment: the only line was:      openpyxl.load_workbook('xlsx file.xlsx')

Comment: You should still include the error message and the line you tried as text. So it can be copy pasted and indexed properly by search engines.
If you look at [`openpyxl.workbook.views`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/_modules/openpyxl/workbook/views.html), I can see that it expects `windowWidth` not `WindowWidth`. Maybe that's the root of the issue? Something might be wrong with your xlsx, try creating a new one and see if you can open it.

Comment: There is either a problem with the file or with openpyxl. In either case we need the file to investigate further.